# using FileReader with select input

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, filereader

I'm trying to convert the following function to read a file from a form select option instead of a file input; not familiar with javascript. have made the changes that appear obvious to me, to no avail.

is there possibly a problem with reading a server-side file vs. a local file?

```
function readTextFile(file, callback, encoding) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    callback(this.result);
});
if (encoding) reader.readAsText(file, encoding);
else reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fileChosen(input, output) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    readTextFile(
        input.files[0],
        function (str) {
            output.value = str;
        }
    );
}
}

$('#files').on('change', function () {
    fileChosen(this, document.getElementById('recipients'));
});
```

i appreciate any help someone can offer...

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? _"to read a file from a form select option"_ How is `File` object stored at `<option>` element? `<option>` elements does not have `.files` property

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the server is of course different from reading a file locally. For the former, you'll likely need to make an API call via AJAX to get your desired file whereas for reading locally you'll want to use something like the FileReader you've provided.

However, what sort of form options are you using to represent the files in HTML? Perhaps what you are intending to do, or you can do instead, is handle the file reading in the server-side code after the form POST?

Comment: I'm populating the select options from basic html files in a folder, just wanting to select one which would then populate the textarea... doesn't really matter how I do it. I don't know enough about ajax or API calls to ask google or stack the right questions, even.

Comment: How are you populating the select options? What does the html for that look like?